# A doubt in Munkres' Topology.

Tags: algebraic-topology

On pg. 343 of Munkres' Topology (Second Edition), there is a diagram given that I am having problems understanding. This diagram is **Figure 51.7**.

Why are the paths $i$ and $e_0$ defined from $I$ to $I$? Shouldn't they mappings from $I$ to $X$?

Sorry I don't have a smartphone right now; I would have attached a photo of the diagram if I did.

Thank you.

Comment: I would love to edit the question in any manner that the downvoter would choose to specify.

Comment: No, he really is considering paths in $I$. He constructs a homotopy of paths in $I$ then applies $f$ to the homotopy.

Comment: Dear algebraically_speaking: dare I ask if  you  are Indian ?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg- Do I satisfy some seemingly common racial stereotype?